# Java multiple HttpSession IDs for the same user

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat, session, jsp

I have some problem with sessions. When I try my project from local sources and refresh several times a JSP that contains the following code:

```
<h1>Session ID=<%=session.getId()%></h1>
```

It always display the same ID. Alright.

The problem is I have deployed the project in a remote server and when I reload the same JSP, it returns me **a different session ID** every time I refresh the page.

The remote server is using **https** (SSL certificate) and a **NGINX** reverse-proxy (if this information helps...).

What am I doing wrong?

Any extra information needed, please tell me and I will give it to you.

PS. More information: if I access to the remote server using its IP and port, it seems that works, giving me the same session ID every time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this modifying some config files in NGINX and Tomcat.

In NGINX, I have deleted the `proxy-cache` lines I've written in the server configuration.

In Tomcat, I have set `context.xml` as follows:

```
<Context path="/" 
         reloadable="false" 
         override="true" 
         useNaming="false" 
         allowLinking="true" 
         useHttpOnly="false" 
         sessionCookiePath="/" 
         sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false"/>
```

And it works! :)